# Java with gradle - unable to load system property

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to read a system property I set from gradle.

I have defined a system property in my gradle.properties file in the root project like this:

```
systemProp.someproperty= cool
```

Then I sync my gradle project and it compiles and runs fine. But in java code I am expecting this system property to be available to the jvm. So I call the following command but it returns null:

```
System.getProperty("someproperty")
```

Can anyone suggest why its null ?

Comment: What do you mean by "sync" your project? Also, how are you running it?

Comment: Are you running the java program from gradle?

Comment: Well it's in Android studio but can be intellij. By sync i mean i ran gradles configuration life cycle. So in other words, gradle executed the build file